# how does Paul Graham solve the circularity of mac in his Bel reference?

Tags: recursion, lisp

in Paul Graham's Bel specification ([bel reference](https://sep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/bel.bel?t=1570993483&))
he defines the 'mac' macro this way:

```
(mac mac (n . rest)
`(set ,n (macro ,@rest)))
```

Isn't this circular? how does the interpreter know what the value of mac is if you are using 'mac' to define mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't being used to define the `mac` operator. The compiler already has built-in knowledge of how to compile macros.

This is used to make the definition visible to application code.

This kind of apparent circularity can be found in most Lisp implementations. Many years ago I was confused when I saw this in the Symbolics source code:

```
(defun car (cons)
  (car cons))
(defun cdr (cons)
  (cdr cons))
(defun cons (car cdr)
  (cons car cdr))
```

There's similar code in SBCL.

It works because the compiler has built-in code generators for these functions. This code is there to create runtime function objects for them, so you can use things like

```
(symbol-function 'car)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the SBCL sources (and I'm sure the CMUCL ones and probably others) have definitions very much like that, today!

Answer (score 1):

Bel isn't implemented, so there is no such problem.  The human intellect reading the specification isn't fazed by the circularity. We read it as "given that we already have a working macro `mac`, here is how it can be defined using itself, and  this definition is to be understood as specifying what `mac` does."

Someone implementing Bel would just use that definition as a guide to create a hand-expanded version of `mac` that doesn't rely on the `mac` syntactic sugar.

The hand-expanded version might look like this:

```
(set mac (macro (n . rest) `(set ,n (macro ,@rest))))
```

So that is to say, we use `set` to associate a `macro` definition with the `mac` symbol like the `mac` macro would if we already had it. Once we do this, we then have `mac`; we can process the original definition  from the spec, if we wish.